# Can't get line numbers in my algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I wrote this code using the algorithm package, I want to add line numbers in the algorithm.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Owen Control Sampling algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
... 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

To this all I get is 0: infront of every line of the algorithm. Please suggest what to do ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried :

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Owen Control Sampling algorithm}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE $N \Leftarrow -n$
\STATE $N \Leftarrow -n$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

And get two well numbered lines. I guess the `…` of your example should be detailed. (A minimal badly numbered example)